# Figure on a0poster

Tags: floats, posters

I am trying to use the below command with `a0poster` style:

```latex
\begin{figure}
%display some image
\end{figure}
```

I am using pdflatex, I am not getting any error, but it is not displaying anything in the poster. How should I fix this? I want to insert forest and trees in the subfigure in the poster. Is there any alternative?

Edit: I am using https://www.latextemplates.com/template/a0poster-portrait-poster template. In this, if the images are placed in the float environment, they disappear.

Comment: Where should the image be put on the poster? Entire background? Or just in-place with other document content?

Comment: In-place with the other text in the poster

Comment: [This minimal example](https://pastebin.com/raw/M5CUMNpU) produces an [image in-place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVkU6.png) without problem. Can you provide something similar that replicates your behaviour?

Comment: Edited the question to include the example

Comment: When you look at the code of the example, it sets a `figure` using the `center` environment and `\captionof{figure}{<your caption>}`. That's what you're supposed to use. Have you tried it?

Comment: That works. But out of curiosity, is there a way to use float environment?